# How can I insert row into table when calling AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProtectionKeyContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("connection-string")

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToDbContext<ProtectionKeyContext>();
```

`ProtectionKeyContext.cs`:

```
public class ProtectionKeyContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
    public  ProtectionKeyContext( DbContextOptions<ProtectionKeyContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DataProtectionKey>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("DataProtectionKeys");
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
                entity.Property(e => e.FriendlyName).HasMaxLength(255);
                entity.Property(e => e.Xml).IsRequired();
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix the error execute the following script in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE DataProtectionKeys(
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FriendlyName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Xml]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DataProtectionKeys] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

*from guardrex : https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/9864*